# MainFragment is missing in Facebook login tutorial

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I tried to run this Android [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) for FB login

but the code fails on this method:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

in this class:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: did you complete the tutorial? did you add the `onActivityResult`, `onResume` etc.. functions?..these functions are important to handle the callback. I went through this tutorial with no troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all the files in your includes? Are you sure all those files are in your build path? Probably aren't make sure your libraries are included.